# Java Sockets Game error

Tags: java, sockets, applet

I followed this tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKBYcE59y9w) and has left me an error:

```
    Unable to start client
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at client.Client.init(Client.java:39)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code:
Client

```
    package client;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static Socket socket;
    static DataInputStream in;
    static DataOutputStream out;

    int playerid;

    int[] x = new int[10];
    int[] y = new int[10];

    boolean left, down, right, up;

    int playerx;
    int playery;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(100, 100);
        addKeyListener(this);
        try {
            System.out.println("Conectando...");
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
            System.out.println("Conectado");
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            playerid = in.readInt();
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Input input = new Input(in, this);
            Thread thread = new Thread(input);
            thread.start();
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(this);
            thread2.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to start client");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateCoordinates(int pid, int x, int y) {
        this.x[pid] = x;
        this.y[pid] = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            g.drawOval(x[i], y[i], 5, 5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (right == true) {
                playerx += 10;
            }
            if (left == true) {
                playerx -= 10;
            }
            if (down == true) {
                playery += 10;
            }
            if (up == true) {
                playery -= 10;
            }
            if (right || left || up || down) {
                try {
                    out.writeInt(playerid);
                    out.writeInt(playerx);
                    out.writeInt(playery);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error sending coordinates");
                }

            }
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37) {
            left = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 38) {
            up = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39) {
            right = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) {
            down = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37) {
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 38) {
            up = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39) {
            right = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) {
            down = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}

class Input implements Runnable {

    DataInputStream in;
    Client client;

    public Input(DataInputStream in, Client c) {
        this.in = in;
        this.client = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                int playerid = in.readInt();
                int x = in.readInt();
                int y = in.readInt();
                client.updateCoordinates(playerid, x, y);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
    package server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static Socket socket;
    static DataOutputStream out;
    static Users[] user = new Users[10];
    static DataInputStream in;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Opening server...");
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
        System.out.println("Server opened...");
        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (user[i] == null) {
                    System.out.println("IP: " + socket.getInetAddress() + " PID: " + user[i].playerid);
                    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    user[i] = new Users(out, in, user, i);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(user[i]);
                    thread.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Users implements Runnable {

    DataOutputStream out;
    DataInputStream in;
    Users[] user = new Users[10];
    String name;
    int playerid;
    int playeridin;
    int xin;
    int yin;

    public Users(DataOutputStream out, DataInputStream in, Users[] user, int pid) {
        this.out = out;
        this.in = in;
        this.user = user;
        this.playerid = pid;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            out.writeInt(playerid);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("PlayerID error");
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                playeridin = in.readInt();
                xin = in.readInt();
                yin = in.readInt();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (user[i] != null) {
                        user[i].out.writeInt(playeridin);
                        user[i].out.writeInt(xin);
                        user[i].out.writeInt(yin);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                user[playerid] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the mistake may be because the version used in the tutorial is older
Thanks for the help

Comment: An applet cannot create socket connection unless it is signed-applet. You have to sign your applet

Answer (score 0):

In server side change.

```
if (user[i] != null) {
  System.out.println("IP: " + socket.getInetAddress() + " PID: " +  user[i].playerid);
  out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  user[i] = new Users(out, in, user, i);
  Thread thread = new Thread(user[i]);
  thread.start();
  break;
 }
```

instead of

```
if (user[i] == null) {
System.out.println("IP: " + socket.getInetAddress() + " PID: " +   user[i].playerid);
out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
user[i] = new Users(out, in, user, i);
Thread thread = new Thread(user[i]);
thread.start();
break;
}
```